# Wordpress export tool doesn't export post-format value of custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, import, export, post-formats

I already created a custom post type with post-format support declared.

```
register_post_type('portfolio', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Portfolio', "xxx"),
            'singular_name' => __('Portfolio', "xxx")
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' )
            )
    );
```

However, when I go to Wordpress Export tool and try to export posts under this custom post type, I checked the exported xml file and saw that it doesn't export post-format value of posts.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After spending time debugging export.php, I found that we have to register post_format taxonomy for our custom post type.

```
register_taxonomy( 'post_format', 'portfolio', array(
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => _x( 'Format', 'post format' ),
                    'singular_name' => _x( 'Format', 'post format' ),
            ),
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => $rewrite['post_format'],
            'show_ui' => false,
            '_builtin' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
```

Easy as that!

Comment: I also commented on the SO version of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30906290/123696

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well. Your solution worked, until I found out that it will *remove* the post format taxonomy for normal post types!

After digging around the core files, I found this function which does exactly what we need:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_format', 'portfolio' );
```

See [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type).